# Failed to make system call with capybara tests

Tags: rspec, webdriver, ruby-on-rails-5, capybara, circleci

I am trying to run some system test build up with capybara, I am getting the following error for all the test:

```
 RuntimeError:
   Failed to make system call: ["/Users/user/Desktop/app/features/support/webdrivers/chromedriver", "--version"]
```

The same error appears when the tests are launch locally or by Circle CI.

I am using the gems:

```
group :development, :test do
  gem 'byebug', platforms: %i[mri mingw x64_mingw]
  gem 'capybara', '~> 2.7', '>= 2.7.1'
  gem 'launchy'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver'
  gem 'webdrivers'
  gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
  gem 'factory_bot_rails'
  gem 'shoulda-matchers'
  gem 'rails-controller-testing'
  gem 'database_cleaner-active_record'
end
```

Comment: Also encountering this issue in github actions with very similar setup